# Dropdownlist in gridview in update panel to trigger client-side confirm box

Tags: asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu, updatepanel

- I have a gridview.
- The Gridview is in an update panel.
- I added a dropdownlist in a template column of the gridview.
- I have autopostback set to true.
- I have code working in the selectedindexchanged event

all of that works great

now I want to add a javascript confirm prompt on client-side change of the dropdowns
I have it popping up the confirm box, but no matter what the user selects (ok or cancel) it does not post back

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlWinnerStatus" runat="server" CssClass="winStatusDDL" OnChange="return ShowWarning(this);"AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlWinnerStatus_OnSelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Can you post the function ShowWarning()?

Comment: ...and the markup of the UpdatePanel. Do you have ChildrenAsTriggers="true"?

Comment: ...and the OnSelectedIndexChanged event code?

Answer (score 1):

First, the [DropDownList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist.aspx) class does not expose an `OnChange` property, so I guess you're doing something like:

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ddlWinnerStatus.Attributes.Add("onchange", "return ShowWarning(this);");
}
```

Now, the problem is that, under the hood, the dropdown list *concatenates* the postback call to your existing `onchange` attribute, which gives something like:

```
<select onchange="return ShowWarning(this); __doPostBack(...);">
```

That's actually more complicated, because `AutoPostBack` is `true` so an additional call to `window.setTimeout()` is inserted, but that's the gist of it, and you can see that `__doPostBack()` never gets called since you're always returning early from the handler.

To achieve what you want, you will have to do all the work yourself, using [GetPostBackEventReference()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153112.aspx) to generate the appropriate call to `__doPostBack()`:

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ddlWinnerStatus.Attributes.Add("onchange",
        String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "if (ShowWarning(this)) {{ {0}; return true; }} else return false;",
            ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(ddlWinnerStatus, "")));
}
```

Note that if you do that, the `AutoPostBack` property becomes redundant (and is effectively ignored).